# How to access a req.something from a middleware outside of the Express.js middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, middleware

I have the following middleware:

```
// verify user from JWT 
function verifyUser(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['Authorization'] || req.cookies.access_token;
  if(token){
    // Split at the space
    const bearer = token.split(' ');
    // Get token from array
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
   jwt2.verify(bearerToken, 'ohnoesmysecretgotleaked', function(err, decoded){
     if(err){
       return res.status(403).send({ 
         success: false, 
         message: 'Failed to authenticate.' 
       });
     }else{
       req.decoded = decoded
       //console.log(decoded.user.lastname);
       req.test = decoded.user.lastname;
       //call function which fetches user specific documents and then hand the values to next
       next()
     }
   })
 }else{
   return res.status(403).send({ 
     success: false, 
     message: 'No token provided.' 
   });
 }
}
```

I need to access a subsubmember of decoded, which I named here `req.test`. The problem is if I try to `console.log` the `req.test` OUTSIDE the middleware I don't get anything printed out or I get `undefined`.

How do I properly access this decoded JWT?

Such a simple problem, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: does `decoded` contain what you're expecting in the callback, even prior to trying to assign to req?

Comment: @Joe yes it does

Comment: And `req.decoded` is also empty/undefined?

Comment: I think I managed to print it out, but not quite. req.decoded is not empty/undefined actually. I'll update with an answer tomorrow when I fully understand the problem/buggy behaviour